# Django Session not properly storing

Tags: django, session

Please I've been trying to fix this for hours now, I need help please. It keeps creating new cart upon each add. I discovered its not getting the session "guest_cart_id". How do I go about it please.

```
 @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def add_to_cart(self, request):
        serializer = AddCartItemSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    user = request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        # Authenticated user
        cart, _ = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    else:
        # Guest user - Check if there's a guest cart in the session
        guest_cart_id = request.session.get('guest_cart_id')
        print(guest_cart_id)
        if guest_cart_id:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(pk=guest_cart_id)
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.create()
            request.session['guest_cart_id'] = str(cart.id)
            request.session.save()
            guest_cart_id = request.session.get('guest_cart_id')
            print(guest_cart_id)

    product_id = serializer.validated_data["product_id"]
    quantity = serializer.validated_data["quantity"]

    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product_id=product_id, cart=cart)
        cart_item.quantity += quantity
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(cart=cart, product_id=product_id, quantity=quantity)

    cart_item_serializer = CartItemSerializer(cart_item)
    response_data = {
        "cart_item": cart_item_serializer.data,
        "cart_id": str(cart.id)  # Convert UUID to string
    }
    return JsonResponse(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```